# Adding short-urls to a blog, makes SEO better or worse?

Tags: seo, url-shortener

HI,

I have a simple blog with a nice friendly-URLs and Google indexes pages as well.

Now i'm going to add a short-url to each post.
So for a sample post, the main URL and link is: **www.blog.com/articles/this-is-a-sample.html**
Also this page is accessible by **www.blog.com/:157**

Does this short-url and links refers by it decrease my page rank? or increases? or nothing special?

Best Regards,
AHHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding Ben's answer, why do not you take a look at how StackOverflow handle this?
Take your own thread for example: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479453/adding-short-urls-to-a-blog-makes-seo-better-or-worse` is resemble "nice friendly-URLs" of your blog, while `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479453/` is the shorter one, similar to your `www.blog.com/:157`

Now if you open this source of this page, you should see  `rel="canonical"` that Ben elaborated above. This tag makes sure that search engines will index the assigned one. Moreover, it is advised that those two links should be clickable, so that users can bookmark the canonical one. Do not miss this thread: [Why do some websites add "Slugs" to the end of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls), it is not tackle your question, yet it gives your deeper insight on your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do that, remember to add

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.blog.com/articles/this-is-a-sample.html" />
```

To `this-is-a-sample.html`, so whatever access `www.blog.com/:157` will look at the canonical tag referring to `this-is-a-sample.html` and won't penalize your site for having duplicated content.

Doing this won't increase or decrease your page rank.

Read more about the canonical tag here:

> http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html