# Tumblr permalinks

Tags: templates, tumblr, permalinks

Can anyone tell me if the title as a part of the Tumblr permalink url is important or can it be left out when sharing a permalink?  For example:

https://brunomars.tumblr.com/post/158078557851/twilvideo-out-now-httpatlanticrtwilvideo
and
https://brunomars.tumblr.com/post/158078557851

both lead to the same post (although the second redirects).  I do see Tumblr's that don't have titles in the permalinks but no options to configure this on Tumblr so I guess it's configured in the template.

Comment: If they both lead to the same post then what's the question? I would assume that only the numeric ID is relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why it's there before I lock in the shorter one (and the implications it might have) to something like a url shortener or a qr code - in both cases permanent and length of the url has an impact.

Comment: "but no options to configure this on Tumblr": Authors can add a slug to the URL in the settings for each post, no?

Comment: I meant for all posts, i.e. enable permalinks with or without titles.  However yes and this comment I think solves my question, thanks.  Copy and paste it into an answer and I'll check it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the permalink with or without URL slug too, they are pointing to the same page, but the long form is more SEO friendly, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls). The only implication is that the share counter will be different for the two urls if you share them on Facebook for example.